# Pandas - How to split single dataframe into multiple dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I wanted to create multiple dataframe and make them into a list of dataframe. I wanted to split it by specifying the veh value. For example, from the datadrame below, I wanted to get 4 single dataframe:

1. ped value 1 with veh value 1
2. ped value 1 with veh value 2
3. ped value 1 with veh value 3
4. ped value 1 with veh value 4

| ped value | veh value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

---

Wanted output:
| ped value| veh value|
| --------------------|
| 1        | 1  |
| 1        | 1  |

| ped value | veh value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

| ped value | veh value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |

| ped value | veh value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

`grouped = df.groupby(['ped', 'veh']) ped_veh1 = grouped.get_group(("P1", 1)) print(ped_veh1)`

The code above is the initial code i used to split the dataframe. However, I got 100 different veh value so is there any way to achieve the output as above?

I have tried using for i in range method:

`for i in range (1,100): grouped = df.groupby(['ped', 'veh']) ped_veh1 = grouped.get_group(("P1", i)) print(ped_veh1)`

However, the code does not work because the value i is not continuous for example:
i = 1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,12

The code stop running when they can't find i = 4 and error is raised.

So, is there any way or solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split Pandas `Dataframe` using `groupby()` function then `get_group`

```
dfs = []
for v in df['veh value'].unique():
    dfs.append(df.groupby('veh value').get_group(v))
```

- Output

```
[   ped value  veh value
 0          1          1
 1          1          1,
    ped value  veh value
 2          1          2
 3          1          2,
    ped value  veh value
 4          1          3
 5          1          3,
    ped value  veh value
 6          1          4
 7          1          4]
```